# Is there an established notion of 'signed treewidth' for signed graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-minors

By a signed graph, I mean a graph where each edge is designated as either odd or even (as in Guenin's result for weakly bipartite graphs).

It is well-known that for (unsigned, or usual) graphs, treewidth $\leq 1$ may be characterized by forbidding $K_3$ as a minor. Similarly, treewidth $\leq 2$ may be characterized by forbidding $K_4$ as a minor, then treewidth $\leq 3$ requires one to forbid 4 different minors (including $K_5$), and so on.

It sometimes seems natural to consider signed graphs that forbid certain signed minors as having 'signed treewidth'. For example, if a signed graph does not contain an odd-$K_3$ as a signed minor (where for any graph $G$, odd-$G$ designates the signed graph that has all edges odd), then we might consider that it has 'signed treewidth' $\leq 1$. Has this idea been explored?